# Reledpar: Continuous pstart numbering when mixing single and double columns

Tags: numbering, columns, reledmac, reledpar

When combining single- and double-column text using reledmac and reledpar, is it possible to have numbered pstarts such that they form a continuous sequence in both the single- and double-columned portions of the text?

In the following MWE, I'd ideally like to have the numbers down the left-hand side run continuously from 1 to 7:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[continuousnumberingwithcolumns]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\renewcommand{\thepstartR}{}

\begin{document}

\numberpstarttrue
\lineation{pstart}

\widthliketwocolumnstrue
\beginnumbering

\pstart
A bit of single-column text.
\pend

\pstart
A load of single-column text that ought to stretch across a couple of lines to give a sense of scale.
\pend
\pausenumbering

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}\resumenumbering\pstart Some left-column text that should have a paragraph number in sequence with the single-column text.\pend
\pstart Additional left-column text.\pend\pausenumbering  \end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}\beginnumberingR\pstart Some right-column text that will be a bit longer. I don't want this side to have paragraph numbers at all.\pend
\pstart Additional right-column text.\pend\endnumberingR 
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}\resumenumbering\pstart Some more left-column text.\pend\pausenumbering\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}\beginnumberingR\pstart Some more right-column text.\pend\endnumberingR\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\resumenumbering
\pstart Some further single-column text. \pend
\pstart And some more single-column text. \pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: That should be a default behavior of reledmac when using pausenumbering/resumenumbering in alternance with two columns. Please open a github issue. That could be solved quickly, I hope.

Comment: Many thanks, Maïeul. Github issue added. One further weird thing, perhaps related, is that the first single-column text *after* a double-column text sometimes won't print the pstart number at all (though it will appear in the notes). I haven't been able to isolate what causes this. Invoking \sidepstartnumtrue seemed to cause it, but apparently not every time.

Comment: as soon as mw computer will be repaired; I will correct the pstart counter problem. Please open an issue for the other problem with a MWE